# Camel Spring DSL Call a method on bean once all all files in a directory have been processed

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I am trying to achieve the following in Camel Spring DSL (Version 2.12.1).

- Read all files from a directory
- Process each file with an `indexer` bean
- Call a `finalizeRepository` method on the indexer bean once all files have been processed

(Based on the answer supplied by Claus I have updated the code sample below with a working solution.)

```xml
<route>
    <from uri="file:./dataToIndex" />
    <bean ref="indexer" method="addDocument(${body}, ${headers.CamelFileNameOnly})" />
    <when>
        <simple>${headers.CamelBatchComplete} == true</simple>
    <bean ref="indexer" method="finalizeRepository" />
    </when>
</route>
```

If the header `CamelBatchComplete` holds the value `true` the method `finalizeRepository` on the `indexer` bean will be called. The header is set to `true` once all documents in the `dataToIndex` directory have been processed.

The only thing I am not quite certain about is the definition of `batch`. 
Is a `batch` determined based on what is found during a single polling event (e.g. if 1k files are found in a directory then this constitutes the batch), or a pattern of polling event (i.e. a series of successfull polls with items followed by a poll without any items is considered a `batch`).

Comment: I don't think you could use splitter or aggregator in this case directly. I would go for: timer/quartz -> custom processor to get all files from the directory -> splitter -> your actual route -> .end() -> finishIndexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file component adds a header when its processing the last file in the batch. You can use that to know when its the last and call the bean.

This is done by other components which supports "batch" as you can find details here

- http://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html